# Detect tags in a logical expression string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

**Description:**

In my Javascript code I have a logical expression as a **string**, like in the example below:

`'foo && !bar || baz'`

Where `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are the names of some tags within my app.

A tag can contain lowercase, uppercase letters, numbers and special characters (+, - , *, #, etc). So the following strings may be valid tags:
`foo-bar`, `foo#`, `f*oo`.

The possible logical operators are: `||` (OR), `&&` (AND) and `!` (NOT).

**Requirement:**

I need to get only the tags from the string above, as an array:

`['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`

**The code I've tried:**
I tried to use the regex `/&&|\|/` to get the logical operators, and then try to invert the logical expression, but without success.

**Other examples:**

`foo && bar` => expected result `['foo', 'bar']`

`foo1 || bar1` => expected result `['foo1', 'bar1']`

`foo+ && !bar&` => expected result `['foo+', 'bar&']`

`foo && bar || baz` => expected result `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply split on the operators:

```js
var text = 'foo && bar& || !baz';
var regex = / *(?:&&|\|\||!) */;
var tags = text
  .split(regex)     // split on operators
  .filter(Boolean); // filter out empty items
console.log('text: ' + text);
console.log('tags: ' + JSON.stringify(tags));
```

Output:

```
text: foo && bar& || !baz
tags: ["foo","bar&","baz"]
```

This test input covers the corner case of consecutive operators (`||` and `!`), and a single `&` as part of the tag name.

Explanation of regex used for split:

- `*` - expect optional space
- `(?:&&|\|\||!)` -followed by all ORed operators; `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group (split includes captured groups in the resulting array)
- `*` - followed by optional spaces

Comment: I found a case when the regex will not work: `foo! && bar` => will return `['foo', 'bar']`

Comment: I edited the regex as follows: `/ *(?:&&|\|\||\B!) */`

Answer (score 2):

You can build your solution in 2 steps as this:

1. Use replace to remove operators using `/(?:\|\||&&|\B!)/g`
2. Split remaining string by whitespace

```js
const arr=['foo! && bar',
'foo1 || bar1',
'foo+ && !bar&',
'foo && bar || baz']

const re = /(?:\|\||&&|\B!)/g

res = []
arr.forEach(el => res.push(el.replace(re, "").split(/\s+/)))

console.log(res)
```

Regex `(?:\|\||&&|\B!)` matches `||` or `&&` or `!` that is not after a word character.